# Open CL error: CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE

Tags: error, opencl

I'm relatively new to blender - I'm using version 2.79. I have been trying to render an animation using GPU with a Hilbert Spiral of 512x512. I keep getting an "Open CL error: CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE" error message. I'm using an AMD Raedeon Pro WX 7100 card.

Are there some settings I missed (all I did was switch CPU to my card in User preferences and GPU in the render panel) or is it possible my card isn't supported by blender?

Thanks

Comment: Your GPU is GCN 4th generation and should be supported. Please try to update your graphics driver and check if that solves the problem.

Comment: Nope - I still get the same error.